# delete all rows from parent and its direct and indirect child tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to delete records of child table and its parent table however there is a catch in this, I have to delete the indirect child of that parent table too.

Let’s take an example to understand more on the problem:

- My Database is very structural and I have specific names associated with some prefix like for Employee data all tables will start with `Emplyee*` tables.
- Each module is having same prefix set of tables. I have almost 20 sets of table for which I have to delete data based on type provided means if Employer is provided, I need to delete data of employer and its employees and its products selected by employees.
- `Employer_Details` has an `ID` (PK) which is reference in all `Employer_*` tables and also in `Employee_MainTable`. `Employee_MainTable` has an `employee_ID` (PK) which is referenced in all `Employee_*` table same with product.

So when I pass Employer as table name and column name as ID to proc, it should delete all data from tables (Employer, Employee and Product) based above condition. If I pass Employee, then it should delete data from `Employee_*` and `Product_*` tables.

I have started a bit but want some expert comment to make it easy. I do not want to mention tables name instead of that I just need some dynamic query which will get all tables based on reference with one more column order number so that I will delete according to order number.

We **don't have cascade delete** as these tables are existing and we can't change them. I want to get this by using **Information_Schema.Tables** means dynamic.

Hope it’s not too complicated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you use cascade or write a query to delete the indirect children rows?

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at this. I already have another answer that works as a decent template for modification. Quick question though, is the depth relationship here always only going to be one? In other words are you always going to be deleting from a child table and want to delete from a parent and all the children of that parent? Do I need to recursively take into consideration whether those children have children?

Comment: Yes. I want to delete data from child table n indirect child table. Table A has direct child table B and C. Table B has direct child Table B1, B2, B3 & same with table C. So when i pass id of table A, all will delete however when i pass table B name & its id then all child table data of B will delete.

Answer (score 2):

if parent has relationship you can use Cascade delete

Comment: These are an existing tables and there are no Cascade delete, so need to delete it by sql query only :)

Comment: Couldn't you alter the tables, so that CASCADE DELETE could work?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables dont have a direct relationship then you are just going to need to write a procedure to delete what you require based on the passed in information

```
DECLARE @TableType varchar(30)

BEGIN
    IF(@TableType = 'Employer')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM MyTable1 WHERE ID = 1234;
        DELETE FROM MyTable2 WHERE ID = 1234;
    END

    IF(@TableType = 'Employee')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM MyTable3 WHERE Employee_ID = 1234;
        DELETE FROM MyTable4 WHERE Employee_ID = 1234;    
    END
END
```

Comment: I don't have 2 tables. Please check question again, i have around 20 tables having referential integrity.